# Windows 10 Start Menu Folder Tiles

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, start-menu

I have created some tiles in my start menu on Windows 10 that point to folders.  Is there any way to get it so that, when I click the tile, it pops up a menu containing the contents?  Right now, if I click it, it brings up the folder in Windows Explorer.

BTW,

```
C:\Users\Administrator>ver

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.657]

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: I am pretty sure the behavior you see is normal. What happens if you right click on the Tile?

Comment: Tiles aren't going to do that. The built-in way to get a cascading menu of folder contents is to add it to the Taskbar as a `Toolbar`. RIght-click the Taskbar > `Toolbars` > `New Toolbar...` > slect desired folder.

Comment: Toolbars will do that for sure. I use the predefined Toolbar called Desktop and my own called Program Files. If you wish to remain using Tiles, then they will work as you already see.

Comment: Actually, it seems that toolbars won't do the job for me either.  If I create a new folder, put shortcuts to all of the folders I want in my toolbar, and then add that folder a toolbar, the folders to which I have shortcuts don't show up as menus.  Just shortcuts which start up explorer.